# Finding a constant such that this function is positive

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Given $0<r<1$, is it possible to find $c>0$ such that the function $\left( \frac{x}{2}-1  \right)^{1+2r}- \frac{1}{c}x^{1+2r}+c$ is positive for $x>2$?

I think that this is true because I have maken some experiments for certain values of $r$, but I would like to find a rigurous proof.

Comment: I suppose the basis are positive...? This means $\;\frac x2>1\,\,x>0\implies x>2\;$ ...?

Comment: Of course! I have just edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The question is equivalent to asking: given $1<s<3$ is there a $c>0$ such that:
$$f(y) := y^s - \frac{2^s}{c}(y+1)^s + c > 0 $$
for all $y>0$ (I just changed the notation slightly).

Let's take $c$ big enough so that $f(1)>0$ and $f'(y)>0$ for all $y\geq1$ (check that we can do that). Thus $f(y)>0$ for all $y\geq1$.

We are now looking for the extremum (minimum) of $f(y)$ on the interval $[0,1]$. It will be $0,1$ or the zero of the derivative of $f$. If $f$ is strictly positive at all of these three points, we get the thesis.

For $c$ big enough $f(0) > 0$ and we already have $f(1) > 0$.

Now find $y_0$ such that $f'(y_0) = 0$. This point $y_0$ is a function of $c$, let's call it $g(c)$.
Now notice that $f(y_0)>0$ for $c$ big enough. That's because $f(g(c))>0$ for $c$ big enough.

Thus we have proven that for $c$ big enough $f(y)>0$ for all $y\geq0$.

Note that we don't need the assumption $s<3$.

Comment: I can write all the calculations explicitly, but maybe you want to do it yourself as an exercise.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: You seem to have put $\;y:=x-1,\,s:=1+2r\;$ , so $\;\left(\frac x2-1)^{1+2r}\right)=\frac{y^s}{2^s}\;$ , but then 

$$\frac{x^{1+2r}}c \rightarrow\frac{(y+1)^s}c $$, and we should have the free $\;c\;$ multiplied by $\;2^s\;$ , and we'd thus get $$y^s-\frac{2^s}c(y+1)^s+ 2^sc\ldots ?$$

Comment: The $s : = 1 + 2r$ is correct, but $y:= \frac{x}{2} - 1$. So the free $c$ stays the same (with no multiplication by $2^s$).

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\Function}[0]{\displaystyle{\left(\dfrac{x}{2} - 1\right)^{1 + 2r} - \dfrac{1}{c}x^{1+2r} + c}}$Given you're looking to show that $\displaystyle{\exists c > 0}$ such that $\Function > 0$, why not employ limits to exhibit that a large enough $c$, will always result in $\Function > 0$;

$$\lim\limits_{c \to \infty}\Function \to 0 + +\infty = +\infty$$

Moreover, to strengthen the above claim (limit), one can even prove $\left(\dfrac{x}{2} - 1\right)^{1 + 2r} > 0$ and $x^{1+2r} >0, \space \forall x > 2$ and hence our limit w.r.t to $c$ is not affected by $x$ or $r$. Overall, it comes to showing that $\left(\dfrac{x}{2} - 1\right)^{1 + 2r} + c >> \dfrac{1}{c}x^{1+2r}$ as $c \to \infty$

Comment: Your second to last sentence makes no sense to me. Could you please explain why our limit is not affected by $x$? All we know is that we have a pointwise convergence to infinity, but how do you get the uniform convergence to infinity from that?

Comment: @Jkbb $\left(\dfrac{x}{2} - 1\right)^{1 + 2r} > 0$ for any $x \in (2, \infty)$, hence the limit with respect to $c$ is not affected by it.

Comment: I agree with your concern about uniform convergence, however, proving that $\left(\dfrac{x}{2} - 1\right)^{1 + 2r}$ is strictly increasing over the given domain may be more valid, which I will leave to the OP after reading this comment.

Comment: I'm sorry but your argument is either invalid or incomplete. It's not enough for these functions to be strictly increasing and positive to guarentee the uniform convergence to infinity.